# Is it possible to write the following query using a subquery but no JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble if the following code is able to be written without a join? Can anyone help explain and write the code without it if it's possible?

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS customer_name,
 state AS customer_state
FROM customers c JOIN addresses a
 ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id
ORDER BY last_name, first_name
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Put a correlated subquery in the select list. (But a JOIN is still the better way.)

Comment: ***Why*** would you want to avoid `JOIN`?  Relational databases are all about joins, that's what join does, relates data from two sources together... *(Although the correlated-sub-query approach doesn't have the `JOIN` keyword in it, it still implements a join in the explain plan)*

Comment: This is for a homework assignment, and I wasn't sure if it was possible or not.

Comment: A join can be replaced with cartesian product between the tables + a where statement. For example: SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS customer_name, state AS customer_state FROM customers c, addresses a WHERE  c.customer_id = a.customer_id ORDER BY last_name, first_name;

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS customer_name,
  (SELECT a.state FROM addresses a WHERE a.customer_id=c.customer_id ) AS customer_state
FROM customers c 
ORDER BY c.last_name, c.first_name
```